# Is Start-Process -Passthru unable to grab the process ID?

Tags: powershell, process, pid, start-process, powershell-5.1

I have a PowerShell script able to open and close `.txt` and `.exe` via a returned PID from `Start-process $type -Passthru`. However, if I try to do this same thing with `.png`s I get this error:

> Start-Process : This command cannot be run completely because the system cannot find all the information required.

I am trying to get a returned PID so I can close the default photo editor without having to explicitly call it by name. Code sample:

```powershell
$object = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-730)} | Select-Object -Property Name  
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $filearray = $object 
$removed = $filearray[-1].Name
$open_photo = Start-Process -FilePath $removed -passthru 
$open_photo.Id
```

Comment: Seems an issue with Microsoft.Photos

Comment: Well it's a bug with MS Store Apps, https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10996#issue-518225514

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking it was a problem with Microsoft Photos itself but was unsure.

Comment: No need to worry, what you're doing as a workaround to find the process is the most reasonable thing to do